# Phonegap - Choose Image From Gallery

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, cordova

Can anyone tell me, or point me in the direction of how to get an image from the phone's image gallery in Phonegap / Android? There's docs on accessing the camera (which works great) but not selecting an existing image.

I'm looking for Phonegap / Javascript rather than Java.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Erm, the `Camera` docs cover this. Is this not working for you? Check out `Camera.PictureSourceType` for details. The docs site givens this example for deriving an image thus:

```
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}
```

`sourceType` is the crucial bit here. It can be `Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA` (the default), or more useful for you it can be `Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY` or `Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM`.

[Camera Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

Comment: Great answer but I think the phonegap docs could do with some pics. It undersells itself. It would also help people with the attention span of a fish like me :) Thank goodness for the readers of things :)

Comment: What's the difference: PHOTOLIBRARY vs SAVEDPHOTOALBUM

Comment: @Mirko what it says on the tin: either the general image library on the device, or a specific album. (Note that there are quirks with these two options on certain versions of Android however).

Comment: @Ben just found the docs: `Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY and Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM both display the same photo album.` so no difference. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: @Mirko you're referring to the current plugin. This post dates back six years, dealing with a far older instance. And back then the two were inter-changeable on certain Android versions, yes (not on iOS).

Comment: @Ben yeah, I think on Android it never made any difference.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use following library: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker
I prefer this one as it's smaller, easy to implement and does not require permission to camera.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/upload_a_picture_using_phonegap_on_android8?lang=en), it may help you.

Sometimes, you may face some problem with uploading an existing image. The solution is simple, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326272/access-files-from-assets-www-directory). Briefly, you need to convert the native Android URI to one that the API can use:

```
// URL you are trying to upload from inside gallery
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(img.URI, function(entry) {
  console.log(entry.fullPath);
  }, function(evt){
    console.log(evt.code);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){

            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){ 
                var sdcard = fileSystem.root;

                sdcard.getDirectory('dcim/camera',{create:false}, function(dcim){
                    var directoryReader = dcim.createReader();
                    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){
                       for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                           entries[i].file(function(f){
                                 var reader = new FileReader();
                                 reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                                 var url= evt.target.result;//base64 data uri

                                 console.log(url)
                                 reader.abort();
                             };
                             reader.readAsDataURL(f);

                           },function(error){
                               console("Unable to retrieve file properties: " + error.code);

                           });

                       }

                    },function(e){
                        console.log(e.code);
                    });


                }, function(error){
                    console.log(error.code);
                });


            }, function(evt){ // error get file system
                 console.log(evt.target.error.code);
            });



        } , true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on [cordova-plugin-photo-library](https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library) plugin which provides cross-platform way to enumerate through all photos on device.

Usage:

```js
cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.getLibrary(function (library) {
    // Here we have the library as array
    cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.getThumbnailUrl(library[0],
        function (thumbnailUrl) { image.src = thumbnailUrl; },
        function (err) { console.log('Error occured'); },
        {
            thumbnailWidth: 512,
            thumbnailHeight: 384,
            quality: 0.8
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hello @viskin. Sorry to hijack but I found your plugin today, but on my phone the code at https://jsfiddle.net/kartagis/pjdqp3ku/ takes ~15 seconds. Should I use localStorage or something to speed the process?

Comment: Please open an issue on github page of the project

Answer (score 0):

Easy

First
    add camera plugin to the project in CMD.

```
F:\phonegap>myapp>cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

And then Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
        <title>PhoneGap app</title>

        <!-- Script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js" ></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-3.0.0.js' ></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Take photo from camera
            $('#but_take').click(function(){
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL 
                });
            });

            // Select from gallery 
            $("#but_select").click(function(){
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, 
                    allowEdit: true,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
                });
            });

            // Change image source
            function onSuccess(imageData) {
                var image = document.getElementById('img');
                image.src = imageData + '?' + Math.random();;
            }

            function onFail(message) {
                alert('Failed because: ' + message);
            }

        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin:0 auto; width:30%!important;text-align: center;">
            <img src="img/cam2.jpg" id='img' style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        </div><br/>
        <div style="width:100%; text-align:center; padding:10px;">
            <button id='but_take'>Take photo</button>
            <button id='but_select'>Select photo from Gallery</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm 100%  sure it works.

the reference is here 
[Choose an image from Camera or Gallery – PhoneGap](http://makitweb.com/choose-an-image-from-camera-or-gallery-phonegap/)