# How to upload file from library with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to upload a file from a phonegap app on my blackberry device to my lamp server.  I followed the tutorials below and they do what the author expects them to do:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer
http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/25/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap/

However, the tutorials do not achieve my objective.  The problem is that the only file I'm allowed to upload is a picture that I immediately take with the camera.  I am not able to browse my Blackberry device for other pictures, audio files, text files and "choose" them.

How do I modify the code in the above examples to allow me to choose a file for upload?  Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that code snippet is all you have used, then you have indeed, overlooked some key areas. You should probably start with [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#DirectoryReader)
 and work towards your goal. I would start by writing a simple file manager type app.

1. Enumerate the entire sdcard or storage tree.
2. When you find the directory you'd like to enter, enter and enumerate it's contents
3. Define a method to select files and upload them.

Comment: Thanks that what i ended up having to do ... writing a my own file manager system

Answer (score 4):

[Phonegap - Choose Image From Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690571/phonegap-choose-image-from-gallery)

As Ben Poole says:

> Erm, the Camera docs cover this. Is this not working for you?
>
> If Camera.sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY or Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM, then a photo chooser dialog is shown, from which a photo from the album can be selected.
>
> http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

You don't have to write your own file manager system, i would vote down Martinez's answer if i could.