# PhoneGap+JQuery_Mobile: How to Get images from the Photo/image Gallery by click on a button

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implemented a **PhoneGap application for andriod and iPhone using jQuery Mobile and java script,**

In the part of my app i have camera option. and i need to use that `image to place in a position.` Thats finished.

I have 2 buttons:

1.Capture Image (Done √)

**2. Choose File From Gallery**

Capture image By click Capture button and place that captured image in the required position. its done

Now **i want the functionality for Get images from Gallery by click another button 'Gallery button'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [PhoneGap Camera Doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture)

> If Camera.sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY or Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM, then a photo chooser dialog is shown, from which a photo from the album can be selected.

For more information check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690571/phonegap-choose-image-from-gallery).

*Add a onclick event listener to your button where you can call the phonegap function ;)