# Image not appear using cordova plugin

Tags: backbone.js, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using two types of cordova plugin to store image into gallery and make retrieve it back.

- File: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file
- Camera: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

My project based on `backbone.js`. But the problem is, I got this weird problem last week. The image still can't appear on the next page after I click button. I got 2 pages, first page to store image into gallery after I capture picture using camera cordova plugin. Below is my code

**page 1**

javascript

```
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('image');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
    localStorage.imageUrl = imageURI;
}
```

html

```
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo
Library</button> <img id="image" name="image" src="" style=
"display:none;width:100%;" />
```

Then I want to retrieve back my image in my gallery using `imageURI` that I store into `localStorage.imageUrl`. I testing using hard corded `imageURI`, retrieve using `console.log`.

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/0CD4797D-0852-4C3A-BC25-C35642799E9E/tmp/cdv_photo_048.jpg
```

**page 2**

html

```
<img id="image" name="image" src="file:///var/mobile/Applications/0CD4797D-0852-4C3A-BC25-C35642799E9E/tmp/cdv_photo_048.jpg" style="display:none;width:100%;" />
```

It didn't working.

So, I try inject imageURI into my view page (page 2) in programmatic way. I create a model and collection for imageURI so i can render it into my second page.

model

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone'], function(_, Backbone) {
    var linkModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            imageUrl: localStorage.imageUrl
        }
        });
    return linkModel;
});
```

collection

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'model/link/linkModel'], function(_, Backbone, linkModel) {
    var linkCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: linkModel
    });
    return linkCollection;
});
```

view

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'model/link/linkCollection', 'text!modules/link/linkConfirmViewTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone, linkCollection, linkConfirmViewTemplate) {
    var LinkConfirmView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function() {
            var variables = {
                imageUrl: localStorage.imageUrl
            };
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(linkConfirmViewTemplate, variables);
            this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
        }
    });
    return LinkConfirmView;
});
<img id="image" name="image" src="<%= imageUrl %>" style="display:none;width:100%;" />
```

I follow this site but still not working.

- http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

I already doing some research for this issue in stakeoverflow, still same.

- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html
- [Phonegap - Choose Image From Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690571/phonegap-choose-image-from-gallery)

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: yes, you can check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I remove `display:none` on my html.

```
<img id="image" name="image" src="" style=
"display:none;width:100%;" />
```

to

```
<img id="image" name="image" src="" style="width:100%;" />
```

Comment: <img id="image" name="image" src="file:///var/mobile/Applications/0CD4797D-0852-4C3A-BC25-C35642799E9E/tmp/cdv_photo_048.jpg" style="width:100%;" />    so this should work? it didnt work for me...