# Browse File or Capture Image and Upload to server using Cordova Inappbrowser in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

I am using [`Cordova` Plugin `Inappbrowser`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) to run my external website on device. In this external website I need to upload an Image `(Gallery/Capture camera)` or file on server. For this I have implemented `HTML5 File API` to make this feature run into my app too. I have tried various [demo 1](http://html5demos.com/file-api-simple), [demo 2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-html5-file-api-to-work-with-files-locally-in-the-browser#a-cooler-demo) and tried this `URL` open into `IAB` to test; unfortunately they didn't work earthier inside my app. Whereas if I try to open these two demo in native browsers like Chrome, safari, firefox apps into my device these demo are allowing me to perform `File API`.

So can anyone help me to fix this issue........

Comment: Have a look at answer of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690571/phonegap-choose-image-from-gallery and this also: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

Comment: I am using IAB of `npm` and I need to implement `HTML5 File API` in IAB.

Comment: if they don't work, the File API ins't supported on the webview of your device. If you want to submit files, try with a form with an input type file

Comment: @jcesarmobile I have tried that `<input type="file">` already. Demo http://html5demos.com/file-api-simple . If I run this demo in native browsers of device then its working fine, whereas if I run inside IAB then its not working. Neither I see any error on console too.

Comment: Input file should work on most android versions, but it doesn't work on some of them. Sorry, but there is no solution for that... Well, maybe using crosswalk engine plugin, but it will increase your app size a lot

Comment: I have tried in various devices with latest OS in Android as well as in iOS. but none of them are working in my app. I am using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser plugin as IAB